# postgresql error in Cloud9 "could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cloud9-ide

I'd like to setup postgresql for my rails app in **Cloud9**.

The following error appeared when I tried to `bundle exec rake db:create`.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
...
```

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.2'
```

/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/**pg_hba.conf**

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   localhost            ubuntu                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             ubuntu                                    md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Although I found similar questions in stackoverflow, they don't work for me.
It would be appreciated if you could advise me on how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `postgresql.conf` file. You have to update the `listen_addresses` to all and make sure to uncomment that line by removing the # mark. So your `listen_addresses` should look like this `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @chalitha lawanga. I have already edited `listen_addresses = '*'` in the `postgresql.conf`.